# Knockout observable - why is this value being updated automatically?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have an array of names that I use to populate a FilterBy radio button list.

```
filterBy = ko.observableArray(["Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc"]);
selectedFilter = ko.observable("Aaa");
```

I display the FilterBy radio button list like this,

```
<div data-bind="foreach: filterBy">
    <input type="radio" name="filterby" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedFilterBy" /><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

I have two buttons - Submit and Cancel. On submit click, I get the selected radio button and assign its value to 'selectedFilterBy' and do the filtering/updating etc. On cancel click, I want restore the selectedfilter. I just noticed that the value of selectedFilterBy is being updated as I select each radio button. I was not expecting 'selectedFilterBy' to update automatically.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) has been set to update the model $parent.selectedFilterBy. So whenever the radio button is clicked the checked binding is invoked and since Knockout is 2 way binding, it will update the specified variable.

> When the user changes which radio button is selected, KO will set your model property to equal the value of the selected radio button"

Comment: Is there an easy way to avoid it? I tried making selectedFilter a regular variable, not a ko observable, but the value is still being updated.

Comment: yes, no matter whether it's a normal variable or an observable, the `checked` binding will update its value. In knockout, view and model are in sync automatically, means you don't need "Submit" and "Cancel" button. If you really need manual control, create two observable, `selectedFilterBy` and `savedFilterBy`, then you can update/restore manually between the two.

Comment: "In knockout, view and model are in sync automatically" - what would be difference between a regular variable and a ko observable?

Comment: Regular variable has no ability to notify others. This means if in your view, there is another `<p data-bind="text: selectedFilterBy"></p>`, ko would not update the <p> tag when you make a selection. If it's an observable, that change will notify the <p> tag to update.